# Responsible design - don't process all the elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am testing responsible design for defined standard resolutions (defined resolutions are get from FireFox). If page width is set to maximum width 650px all works, but if I change browser width to 651px and more, CSS code is not process. I don't see problem.

```js
        window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
        window.onload = displayWindowSize;

        function displayWindowSize() {
            myWidth = window.innerWidth;
            myHeight = window.innerHeight;
            // your size calculation code here
            document.getElementById("responsible-design-debug").innerHTML = "Responsible design debug: " + myWidth + "x" + myHeight;
        };
```

```css
        body {
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
        }

        .Logo {
            height: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  1920px and more
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 1920px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: green;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  1280px - 1920px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: lightgreen;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  980px - 1280px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: red;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  800px - 980px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 979px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: orange;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  768px - 800px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 799px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: blueviolet;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  360px - 768px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: blue;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  320px - 360px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: aqua;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  0px - 320px
         * ORIENTATION: Portrait
        **/
        @media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 319px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: yellow;
                float: left;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsible design</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="responsible-design-debug" class="responsible-design-debug">Responsible design debug: init</div>
    <img src="Image.png" alt="Image.png" class="Logo" />

    <div id="example">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer In et elit diam arcu. Lacus enim molestie dictumst quis convallis pellentesque consectetuer ipsum ligula pellentesque. Nullam elit nunc amet et nec semper lacus ac lacinia et. At Sed Proin tempor lacus tristique senectus eu est lacinia dui. Nisl Ut Vestibulum ac Vestibulum Phasellus lacinia ut auctor consequat felis. Sapien dolor Morbi Ut fringilla at molestie eu.</p>
        <p>Augue sodales est ligula eget cursus quis id orci magna et. Dapibus ac elit diam pede mauris Nam interdum adipiscing et suscipit. Nonummy justo laoreet In elit magna condimentum enim quis non tempor. Malesuada eget habitant ligula ut consequat ut felis amet libero cursus. Lobortis tellus volutpat pellentesque leo ipsum id Vestibulum suscipit convallis Donec. Amet eget dui.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you and best regards,
 Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `and (orientation: portrait)`, so once the width of the window has a higher value than the height, none of your CSS will be taken into account because it's considered `landscape` orientation at that point. If you remove that from all your media queries it will work as expected:

```js
window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
window.onload = displayWindowSize;

function displayWindowSize() {
  myWidth = window.innerWidth;
  myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  // your size calculation code here
  document.getElementById("responsible-design-debug").innerHTML = "Responsible design debug: " + myWidth + "x" + myHeight;
};
```

```css
body {
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
        }

        .Logo {
            height: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  1920px and more

        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: green;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  1280px - 1920px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: lightgreen;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  980px - 1280px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: red;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  800px - 980px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 979px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: orange;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  768px - 800px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 799px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: blueviolet;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  360px - 768px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: blue;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  320px - 360px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: aqua;
                float: left;
            }
        }

        /**
         * DEVICE:      Universally
         * DIMENSIONS:  0px - 320px
        **/
        @media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 319px) {
            .responsible-design-debug {
                background-color: yellow;
                float: left;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Responsible design</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="responsible-design-debug" class="responsible-design-debug">Responsible design debug: init</div>
  <img src="Image.png" alt="Image.png" class="Logo" />

  <div id="example">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer In et elit diam arcu. Lacus enim molestie dictumst quis convallis pellentesque consectetuer ipsum ligula pellentesque. Nullam elit nunc amet et nec semper lacus ac lacinia et. At Sed Proin tempor lacus tristique
      senectus eu est lacinia dui. Nisl Ut Vestibulum ac Vestibulum Phasellus lacinia ut auctor consequat felis. Sapien dolor Morbi Ut fringilla at molestie eu.</p>
    <p>Augue sodales est ligula eget cursus quis id orci magna et. Dapibus ac elit diam pede mauris Nam interdum adipiscing et suscipit. Nonummy justo laoreet In elit magna condimentum enim quis non tempor. Malesuada eget habitant ligula ut consequat ut
      felis amet libero cursus. Lobortis tellus volutpat pellentesque leo ipsum id Vestibulum suscipit convallis Donec. Amet eget dui.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working. May I ask you for clarification the issue? I have read that the orientation CSS methods (features: portrait) and (orientation: landscape) are used for detected device how users the device hold. According to your description - if I want to have responsible design, is reccomended don't specify orientation and work only with width?

Comment: Correct, I have built many responsive websites and I have rarely ever used `orientation` in my media queries. Of course there are situations where you would want to, but in my experience they are very rare. For the most part, you can simply use `@media only screen and (min-width: XXXpx)` to accomplish responsive design(note that max-width is not even necessary). For me, the best way to approach responsive design is to start by defining mobile styles(mobile first) and then use media queries for [progressive enhancement](https://medialoot.com/blog/progressive-enhancement-web-design/)